# :first-child selecting two elements

Tags: css, formatting

I am trying to format the text 'Portfolio' only, using the CSS below. However, this is also selecting the text 'Client' also. I do not understand why this is the case when I am selecting `:first-child`? Is it because I have a second class `.group2`, which then makes the text 'client' a first child? Although it is not the first-child of portfolio still. What is the logic here?

```
<div class="portfolio">
    <div class="container">
        <h3>Portfolio</h3>
    <div class="group1">
        <img src="http....." style="height: 506px; width: 675px">
    <div class="group2">
        <h3>Client</h3>
        <h4>JPMorgan</h4>
        <h3>Role in Project</h3>
        <h4>Project Lead</h4>
        <h3>Project Included</h3>
        <h4>Mobile and Web Interface</h4>
        <a href="#">Browser</a>
    </div>
    </div>
    </div>
    </div>

<style>    

 .portfolio h3:first-child {
 color: #292929;
 border-bottom: 3.5px solid #E1E1E1;
 width: 130px;
 margin: 0px auto;
 font-size: 1.5em;
 text-transform: uppercase;
 text-shadow: 0px 0px 1px #292929;
 text-align: center;
 padding-bottom: 10px;
 font-family: inherit;
 }
</style>
```

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? Are you trying to get the very first h3 in the DOM? Are you trying to get the first h3 in a specific parent?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
.container > h3 {
 color: #292929;
 border-bottom: 3.5px solid #E1E1E1;
 width: 130px;
 margin: 0px auto;
 font-size: 1.5em;
 text-transform: uppercase;
 text-shadow: 0px 0px 1px #292929;
 text-align: center;
 padding-bottom: 10px;
 font-family: inherit;
 }
```

Comment: Thank you this works. But I am not getting it. Why was first child originally selecting both elements? And how does this solution differ, in that it is still point to the h3:first-child? I know it is a sound solution, but I do not understand the logic and reasons behind it.

Comment: Because you were saying .portfolio h3:first-child and it was selecting the first child of h3 in both elements, with my code, your telling it to select first-child of h3 in the .container element, I will rectify my code again to show you a even better way to do this.

Comment: Thank you. So what is the function of the '>' symbol? Does it mean to select the first-child also?

Comment: No for example if you want to select the h3 in .container, you can do it 2 ways by doing ".container > h3" or "container h3" the reason you would use > is if you would like to work your way down the hierarchy of the elements 1 by 1 rather then trying to access the h3 element 4 or 5 nested elements down, if you need to that then you could simply use "container h3" and this will make changes to all h3 elements in .container regardless of how nested they are.

Comment: Ok, cool, so it means immediate children then I suppose, in short?

Comment: Yes, > means immediate child, no > means all the h3 childs in .container, Hope I have solved your issues :)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/81785/discussion-between-c-had1990-and-mugman).

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is the selector:

```
.portfolio h3:first-child
```

This selects any h3 that is the first child of h3's parent. Note that this parent doesn't need to be a `.portfolio`!

```
.portfolio > div > h3:first-child
```

With this notation, you explicitly define the path of the DOM you want to have. The h3 has to be within a `<div>`, which has to be within `.portfolio`.

Comment: This kind of makes sense. However, even with the code you have given, the text 'client' is still within a <div>, which is within <container>, which is within <portfolio>, how is it differentiating it?

Comment: With your constelation you would need something like `.portfolio > .container > .group1 > .group2 > h3:first-child`.

Answer (score 1):

Hei!

Yes, "The :first-child CSS pseudo-class represents any element that is the first child element of its parent."
In this case h3 with "Client" is a first child of a parent. The parent is .group2.